# How to do data enrichment on CSV file with Apache NiFi using SimpleDatabaseLookupService

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I have a `csv` file like this:

```txt
ProductId,CategoryId
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
...
... nearly 1 million records
```

From this `csv`, I want to produce another `csv` like below:

```txt
ProductId,CategoryId,ProductName,CategoryName
1,1,Shirt,Mens
1,2,Shirt,Boys
1,3,Shirt,Uni
2,1,Watch,Mens
2,2,Watch,Boys
2,3,Watch,Uni
```

To this, I have setup NiFi flow as below:

```
GetFile 
        -> LookupRecord 
           -> uses SimpleDatabaseLookupService to query DB table "PRODUCT" using ProductId to get ProductName
           -> uses CSVRecordSetWriter to write the ProdcutName value back to the CSV
        -> LookupRecord
           -> uses SimpleDatabaseLookupService to query DB table "CATEGORY" using CategoryId to get CategoryName
           -> uses CSVRecordSetWriter to write the CategoryName value back to the CSV
```

This works, atleast on files which has about 40K lines. But, as soon as I feed the original file containing over a million records, NiFi just hangs.

So my questions is:
Is there a way to optimize my flow, which can work with such large data sets ?

**Note**: there is a repetition of ProductId and CategoryId in my file. My current flow executes for each row. I was wondering if this fact can be leveraged to optimize the flow, but I couldn't figure out how. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check your cluster utilization (you have it in nifi ui). Probably you just need stronger cluster.

Comment: Add a SplitRecord before the LookupRecord to chunk it in to smaller 40k batches so that you aren't waiting for all 1 million lookups to complete before progressing